# Laravel 7: How to edit the message in verification email

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to edit Laravel default email verification message.
I have tried publishing the notification and mail resources.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

New folders called mail and notification were created in resource>views>vendor but I haven't been able to find the file which holds the codes for the message in either of the folders. I found a file that seems like the one in vendor>laravel>framework>src>Illuminate>Auth>Notification which is called VerifyEmail but I'm not sure if I'm suppose to change this file since I couldn't find any article online talking about this file.
My Laravel version is 7.15.0.

Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From [Views](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/verification#verification-views): "_The email verification view is placed in resources/views/auth/verify.blade.php. You are free to customize this view as needed for your application._" after installing `laravel/ui`

Comment: Hi there,
I checked the file you mentioned and I think you are talking about the page which tells people that link for verification has been sent. I meant the message in the actual mail.

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66636241).